# how to integrate facebook in java application

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

this my redirect URl into facebook

```
String uri = "";
    FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(MCRUtil.getMcrResourceBundle().getString("facebook.clientId"), MCRUtil.getMcrResourceBundle()
          .getString("facebook.clientSecret"));
    OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
    OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();

    String param = request.getParameter("param");
    if (param.equalsIgnoreCase("signUp")) {
        uri = redirectUri + "fbSignUp.htm";
    } else if (param.equalsIgnoreCase("friend")) {
        uri = redirectUri + "m-auth-fbfriends.htm";
    }
    params.setRedirectUri(uri);
    params.setScope("email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_likes,user_status,publish_stream,friends_about_me,publish_actions,read_friendlists");
    params.setScope("email");
    params.set("display", "popup");
    String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
    return "redirect:" + authorizeUrl;
```

i am using facebookconnectionfactory

this code will redirect to facebook login then i want to store the user details in my database.so redirect another service in that is below

```
String facebookAccessToken = request.getParameter("code");
    if (facebookAccessToken == null) {
        return "socialError";
    }
    UserVO customer = null;
    AccessGrant accessGrant = null;
    /* By using clientId and secret getting connection facotiry */
    FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(MCRUtil.getMcrResourceBundle().getString("facebook.clientId"), MCRUtil.getMcrResourceBundle()
          .getString("facebook.clientSecret"));
    String uri = redirectUri + "fbSignUp.htm";

    OAuth2Operations oauthOperations=connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();        

    accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(facebookAccessToken, uri,null);
    Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
    Facebook facebook = connection.getApi();
    FacebookProfile userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
    UserVO userVO = new UserVO();
    userVO.setEmail(userProfile.getEmail());
    userVO.setFirstName(userProfile.getFirstName());
    userVO.setLastName(userProfile.getLastName());
```

here i am getting accessGrant null data .. accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(facebookAccessToken, uri,null); .. i am using spring-social-core-1.1.0 jar can you help me how to get accessGrant values...

thanks in advance

Comment: any another way to get accessGrant values from oauth2Operation..

Comment: tell me..some solution for this AccessGrant authentication